# How to show a specific JPanel when a specific JMenu is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jmenu

I'm trying to build a project which has many i.e about 5 JMenus, so when you click any of the it displays a specific JPanel which is different from the panels of the other menus. Any idea how to code it would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a CardLayout or a JTabbedPane.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html

Comment: Asked follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62969737/how-to-switch-jpanel-cards-when-a-jmenu-is-clicked. Why did you delete the follow up question? Did the suggestions help? Is the problem solved?